# How does setTimeout expect success and/or failure callbacks

Tags: javascript, html, promise, callback, settimeout

I am going through the Using Promises article on MDN. In one [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api) they mention the following:

> In an ideal world, all asynchronous functions would already return promises. Unfortunately, some APIs still expect success and/or failure callbacks to be passed in the old way. The most obvious example is the setTimeout() function

Upon reading the documentation for the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function, I don't find any success or failure callback required. We just provide a callback function which always executes and if this function succeeds or fails, it will not trigger any success and/or failure callback like a promise.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for `setTimeout` to accept a failure callback. That is just bad juxtaposition of language. The author simply bemoans that `setTimeout` doesn't allow `await setTimeout(1000)` out of the box.

Comment: `setTimeout(successCallback, 1000)` does accept a callback. It doesn't accept a failure callback.

Answer (score 1):

An asynchronous function doesn't necessarily have a concept of failing in some way. Almost all do, but a few don't, such as `setTimeout` - the callback will run regardless once the time is up and nothing's blocking the engine.

`setTimeout`'s callback running could be said to be the success callback. (It never fails - your *if this function succeeds or fails* refers to something inside the handler deciding on the success/failure logic, rather than the asynchronous function itself deciding on the success/failure logic)

Some asynchronous functions (that don't support promises) accept an error callback - such as `.on('error', errorHandler)`. Other times, they support a single callback which is called regardless of success or failure, such as `.on((error, result) => {` (so to say that there's always a "success callback" or separate "failure callback" isn't quite right).`setTimeout` is just a slight oddity in that it just doesn't have any concept of failure to begin with.

Comment: Arguably `clearTimeout()` could be seen as a "failure" (or abortion) of the scheduled callback.